# Wot convergence and sot convergence

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $\{A_n\} $ be a sequence of bounded linear operators on Hilbert space $H$ and $\langle A_n\xi,\eta \rangle \to \langle A \xi,\eta\rangle$ for $\xi,\eta\in H$ with $\|\eta\|=1$. Show that $\|A_n\xi -A\xi\|\to 0$.

My attempt: Without loss of generality, suppose $\langle A_n\xi,\eta\rangle \to 0$. For $\epsilon>0$ if $n$ is sufficiently large, then $$|\langle A_n\xi,\eta\rangle|<\epsilon $$  I need to show that $\|A_n\xi\|<\epsilon$, while I do not have any idea. Please help me. Thanks.

**added:**

[image]
[image]

Comment: This isn't true as stated.  For instance, let $T$ be the right-shift operator on $\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$, let $A_n = T^n$ and let $A=0$.  Then the hypothesis holds (exercise) but $\|A_n \xi - A \xi\| = \|T^n \xi\| = \|\xi\|$ since $T$ is an isometry, and we do not have $\|A_n \xi - A \xi\| \to 0$.  Have you missed another hypothesis?

Comment: @NateEldredge: That's problem 107 of Halmos book"A Hilbert space problem book". I added its picture

Comment: Ah, you left out the critical word "uniformly".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without loss of generality, assume $A = 0$. Let $\epsilon > 0$. Since $\langle A_n\xi,\eta\rangle \to 0$ uniformly for $\|\eta\| = 1$, there exists an index $N = N(\epsilon)$ such that if $n\ge N$, $|\langle A_n\xi,\eta\rangle| < \epsilon/2$ for all $\eta \in H$ with $\|\eta\| = 1$. Thus, if $n \ge N$, $$\|A_n\xi\| = \sup_{\|\eta\| = 1}|\langle A_n\xi,\eta\rangle| \le \frac{\epsilon}{2} < \epsilon.$$ Since $\epsilon$ was arbitrary, $\|A_n\xi\| \to 0$.

Comment: oh, because it stated uniformly, there is a $N$ in dependable of $\eta$